# How do you print just the stats line when using FFplay?

Tags: ffmpeg, powershell

In FFmpeg printing just the stats line in the console is as simple as including `-loglevel quiet -stats`, but the same does not work in FFplay.

Running these arguments I just get nothing in the console:

```
$argumentList = @("-loglevel", "quiet", "-stats", "-i", "-x", "848", "-y", "480", "`"$filePath`"")
```

Is it possible to make FFplay less verbose without losing the main stats line?

Comment: Yes, the status is processed through the logging system in ffplay, unlike ffmpeg, I'll send a patch to change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was bug [6962](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6962). Now fixed. Add `-stats` to force display.